# Unable to figure out required (to be deleted) Documents as information is not consistent

Tags: mac, storage, big-sur

I am trying to free up some space (around 20GB) in order to install Big Sur on my 2019 Air, 128GB.

Under Storage Management, I select Documents that are shown to occupy 36GB of space. However, there are no Large Files, Downloads, or Unsupported Apps. When I click the File Browser option, the files and folders listed don't sum up to the size mentioned in the Recommendations.

The pic below showcases my situation:
[image]

Comment: show hidden files (open finder, then hit `shift`+ `cmd`+ `.`) and check your library folder

Comment: Please answer this so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This file size discrepancy most likely occurs due to hidden files in the `user/library` folder.

To show hidden files, open a Finder window and hit <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>cmd</kbd> <kbd>.</kbd>. You will immediately see that these files are shown with grey text in finder.

---

However, be careful with deleting these, you can harm the system or programs by doing so.

Comment: You are unlikely to harm the system or apps by deleting stuff in the user Library -- a brand new user account will have nothing there, for example. Most apps will save what they need there on first run.